# jQuery addClass() to element generated after append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to a newly appended DIV without using something like:

```
t.y.append('<div class="lol'+i+'"></div>');
```

Here's a better example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var t = this;

$(this.x).each(function(i, obj) {
    //append new div and add class too <div></div>
    t.y.append('<div></div>').addClass('lol'+i);
});
```

Page load HTML looks like:

```
<div class=".slideButton0 .slideButton1 .slideButton2" id="sliderNav">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your better example does indeed look better. What is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you append an element through `.append`, it doesn't change the context of the jQuery object.

You could write it like this:

`$('<div></div>').appendTo(t.y).addClass('lol'+i);`

or

`$('<div></div>').addClass('lol'+i).appendTo(t.y);`

(these both do the same thing, simply in different orders, the second possibly being more clear)

the context of the jQuery object will be the newly created div.

Comment: I was about to post this, `appendTo` is definitively the most elegant solution to OP's case.

Comment: What is the main difference between this solution and `Mark Reed`, `Gromer` solution. Which is more efficiant and why?

Comment: Well, `appendTo` effectively turns around and calls `append`, but I doubt there's any significant efficiency difference.  So I'd say it comes down to which code you'd rather read.

Comment: I would still do the `addClass` first, just to be clearer about what's happening: `$('<div/>').addClass('lol'+i).appendTo(t.y)`.

Comment: @DanKanze this solution is more elegant, really. They all do basically the same thing, and their answers are essentially identical. jQuery wraps DOM elements with the jQuery object, so unless the objects are filtered in some way, the "context" will always be those objects. When calling `append`, it will generate the new markup (when necessary), and append it to the current context, but the context remains the same, so `addClass` will be applied to that context instead of the newly created div.

Answer (score 7):

```
t.y.append('<div></div>').addClass('lol'+i);
```

should be

```
t.y.append('<div></div>').find('div').addClass('lol'+i);
```

In the first case you are adding class  to the div to which you are appending .. 
SO the context is still the **parent div** and not the **newly appended** div..

You need to find it first inside the parent and then add the class..

**EDIT**

If you want to just add the class to the last appended element ... Find the last div in the parent and then add the class to it..
This will make sure you are not adding the class to all the div's every single time you iterate in the loop..

```
t.y.append('<div></div>').find('div:last').addClass('lol'+i);
```

Comment: correct, no other divs. however what I am seeing is that each iteration appends an additional `'lol'+1`. For example: `<div class='lol1 lol2 lol3'></div>`

Comment: Seems silly to add your new div to a container and then root around inside that container looking for it, when you could just add the class while you still have a grasp on the div you just created...

Comment: @MarkReed .. Yup.. thats true.. Instead of that we can use appendTo or write the code herein the context is the newly added div.. I just wanted to point out where the OP was missing his logic..

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`t.y.append($('<div></div>').addClass('lol'+i));`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/QkTdq/

Comment: What is the main difference between this solution and `Shmiddty` solution. Which is more efficiant and why?

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = this;

$(this.x).each(function(i, obj) {
    //append new div and add class too <div></div>
    var d = $('<div />').addClass('lol' + i);
    t.y.append(d);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `append` returns the container instead of the thing you just appended to it.  I would just do the `addClass` *before* the `append` instead of after:

```
var t = this;

$(this.x).each(function(i, obj) {
    //append new div and add class too <div></div>
    t.y.append($('<div></div>').addClass('lol'+i));
});
```

**EDIT** ... or, in other words, exactly what Gromer said.  Beat me by five whole minutes, too.  I'm getting slow.

Comment: What is the main difference between this solution and `Shmiddty` solution. Which is more efficiant and why?

Comment: As I said in my comment on @schmiddty's answer, I doubt there's a significant efficiency difference, but I do like the flow of Schmiddty's version better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention why you want to number the `class` attribute to your list items, but in the case that you are actually using them for css don't forget you have :odd and :even css selector attritbutes and also the equivalent odd/even jQuery selectors.

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html
http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything like this. notice the class attribute!

```
$.each(obj, function (_index, item) {
    resultContainer.append($('<li>', {
      class: "list-group-item",
      value: item.id,
      text: item.permitHolderName || item.permitHolderId
    }));
});
```