# Chaining methods to a newly inserted element via append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While trying to find a solution to this problem I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923970/jquery-addclass-to-element-generated-after-append) which suggests using the `appendTo` method like so:

```
$('<input[type="text"]').appendTo('div').addClass('foo');
```

There are times where I'm using `append` more than the former. Is there a way I can chain methods to a newly inserted element using `append`?

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<a href="#">Add new element</a>

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('div').append('<input type="text" />').addClass('bar');
});
```

Comment: No you would need to use `appendTo` or do a `find` afterwards if you want to chain like that. You can however create the new element with jquery and modify inline as you call append as @antyrat has outlined in his answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that, in that specific example (though perhaps some others, depending on the precise requirements), you could simply use: `$('div').append('<input type="text" class="bar" />');` though, obviously, it does depend on what you want to achieve and what methods you want to chain.

Comment: @DavidThomas So going that route `appendTo` I'm guessing that you have to use `appendTo`?

Comment: No, to add an element with specific attributes/properties that can be assigned via html (such as the `className`, as above) you can use `append()` as shown. But, obviously, that only works for those attributes/properties that can be given via markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to use `append` you can pass jQuery object to it instead of HTML:

```
$('div').append($('<input type="text" />').addClass('bar'));
```

```js
$('div').append($('<input type="text" />').addClass('bar'));
```

```css
.bar {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```